# TSQL change cursor definition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I'm using a cursor.

```
DECLARE @column1 NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c1
    FROM   table_name;

OPEN cursor_name;
FETCH cursor_name INTO @column1;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    FETCH cursor_name INTO @column1;
END

CLOSE cursor_name;
DEALLOCATE cursor_name;
```

Now my question is, can I change the cursor `cursor_name`'s definition after using it? I mean something similar to:

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c2
    FROM   table_name2;
```

Using the same cursor name `cursor_name`, but the defination is changed. 
If this is possible, how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Yes it's possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172595%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), but it has to be after your DEALLOCATE it.  Have you tried this and it's not working or something?

You may also want to look at whether you really need a cursor.  They hurt performance and SQL that uses them can often be rewritten without them.

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258842%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) which goes over how to do it.  They use the less common DECLARE/SET syntax for declaring a cursor (uncommon in my world at least).  Here is the example they provide:

```
USE pubs
GO
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR LOCAL SCROLL FOR
SELECT * FROM titles

DEALLOCATE @MyCursor

SET @MyCursor = CURSOR LOCAL SCROLL FOR
SELECT * FROM sales
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

Avoiding the discussion of whether or not a cursor is necessary, from a purely technical point of view, once the cursor is closed and deallocated, you are free to reuse the name again.